# Converting SpatialPoints to Normal for exporting .csv

Tags: r

I have a rasterbrick and point shapefile. I have working code for extracting values of pixels from spatial points, but I need to export results to .csv file. I suppose that the key of this problem is to convert SpatialPointsDataFrame to normal one. But I do not know how to complete this task. Here is part of my code:

```
library(rgdal)
library(raster)
library(ggplot2)

# setting working directory
vstupni_adresar <- choose.dir(getwd(), "Zadej cestu k pracovnímu adresáři")
prac_adresar <- setwd(vstupni_adresar)

# choose a raster brick
r <- brick(choose.files(caption = "Načti data vstupující do klasifikace"))

# choose directory, where point shapefile is located
vyber_shp <- choose.dir(getwd(), "Vyber adresář, kde se nachází trénovací data")

# extract values from shapefile
sdata <- readOGR(dsn = vyber_shp, layer = "trenink")
sdata@data <- na.omit(data.frame(sdata@data, extract(r, sdata)))

# export to vsv
df <- fortify(sdata)
csv_zapis <- write.csv(df, file="Data_extrakce.csv")
```

Answer (score 2):

First, this line, nesting na.omit `sdata@data <- na.omit(data.frame(sdata@data, extract(r, sdata)))`
 is very dangerous and will likely break your spatial object.

The @data slot is the data.frame associated with your spatial object. If it a point feature class and you would like to save it with the associated coordinates you can pull them from the @coordinates slot.

```
library(sp)
data(meuse)
coordinates(meuse) <- ~x+y
head(meuse@data)
( df <- data.frame(x=coordinates(meuse)[,1], y=coordinates(meuse)[,2], meuse@data) )
write.csv(df, "mydata.csv", row.names=FALSE)
```