# Create KML from CSV file, with 2 sets of lon-lats (instead of 1)

Tags: r, kml

Having the dataframe:

```
lon-1 lat-1 lon-2 lat-2 some_val
```

And using the R code:

```
coordinates(mydata)<-~lon_start+lat_start+lon_end+lat_end
proj4string(mydata) <- CRS("+init=epsg:28992")
mydata_ll <- spTransform(mydata, CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"))
writeOGR(wwverkeer_ll["some_val"], "mydata.kml", layer="some_val", driver="KML")
```

I get an unexpected output (kml file) containing:

```
<Placemark>
  <ExtendedData><SchemaData schemaUrl="#some_val">
      <SimpleData name="some_val">3228</SimpleData>
  </SchemaData></ExtendedData>
   <Point>
<coordinates>3.xxxxxx,47.yyyyyyy,54.zzzzzzzz</coordinates></Point>
   </Placemark>
   <Placemark>
```

Where I would actually like to have 4 coordinate points, instead of 3.
And some certainty on this being the correct coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

Adapting python code from: [Converting SpatialPoints to Normal for exporting .csv](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/210403/converting-spatialpoints-to-normal-for-exporting-csv)

One gets:

```
import csv
#Input the file name.
fname = raw_input("Enter file name WITHOUT extension: ")
data = csv.reader(open(fname + '.csv'), delimiter = ',')
#Skip the 1st header row.
data.next()
#Open the file to be written.
f = open('csv2kml.kml', 'w')

#Writing the kml file.
f.write("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>\n")
f.write("<kml xmlns='http://earth.google.com/kml/2.1'>\n")
f.write("<Document>\n")
f.write("   <name>" + fname + '.kml' +"</name>\n")
for row in data:
    f.write("   <Placemark>\n")
    f.write("       <name>" + str(row[6]) + "</name>\n")
    f.write("       <Point>\n")
    f.write("           <coordinates>" + str(row[1]) + "," +     str(row[2]) + "," + str(row[3]) +  "," + str(row[4]) + "</coordinates>\n")
    f.write("       </Point>\n")
    f.write("   </Placemark>\n")
f.write("</Document>\n")
f.write("</kml>\n")
print "File Created. "
print "Press ENTER to exit. "
raw_input()
f.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

The three numbers in the `<coordinates>` tag are long, lat, and height. I think what you really want is two `<point>` tags within each `<placemark>`. Your data is a MULTIPOINT data set, and the `sp` class you are using doesn't support that very well (if at all).

If you switch to the newer `sf` classes then you have full support for MULTIPOINT data, including writing to KML. The example in ?read_sf shows the creation of a MULTIPOINT data (via GeoJSON) and when writing that to a KML using `st_write` I get:

```
 <Placemark>
      <MultiGeometry>
       <Point><coordinates>3.2,4.0</coordinates></Point>
       <Point><coordinates>3.0,4.6</coordinates></Point>
       <Point><coordinates>3.8,4.4</coordinates></Point>
       <Point><coordinates>3.5,3.8</coordinates></Point>
```

etc, which could be what you want.